# Select based on status

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this SQL query which is used to count components:

```
SELECT COUNT(CS.COMPONENTTYPEID) AS CNT
FROM COMPONENTTYPE CT LEFT
OUTER JOIN COMPONENTSTATS CS ON CS.COMPONENTTYPEID = CT.COMPONENTTYPEID
WHERE CT.COMPONENTTYPEID IN (?, ?)
GROUP BY CT.NAME,
         CT.COMPONENTTYPEID
ORDER BY CT.COMPONENTTYPEID
```

I want to select all components which have `status = 'Active'`. Where is the correct position in which I have to insert it? Maybe this:

```
SELECT COUNT(CS.COMPONENTTYPEID) AS CNT
FROM COMPONENTTYPE CT LEFT
OUTER JOIN COMPONENTSTATS CS ON CS.COMPONENTTYPEID = CT.COMPONENTTYPEID
WHERE CT.COMPONENTTYPEID IN (?, ?) WHERE STATUS = 'Active'
GROUP BY CT.NAME,
         CT.COMPONENTTYPEID
ORDER BY CT.COMPONENTTYPEID
```

Comment: which table is STATUS coloumn COMPONENTSTATS or COMPONENTTYPE

Comment: STATUS is in table COMPONENTSTATS

Comment: What table `Status` comes from?  If you need two conditions in WHERE then (in your case) you use `AND`. As in `WHERE ... AND ...`

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT COUNT(CS.COMPONENTTYPEID) AS CNT
FROM COMPONENTTYPE CT 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN COMPONENTSTATS CS ON CS.COMPONENTTYPEID = CT.COMPONENTTYPEID AND CS.STATUS = 'Active'
WHERE CT.COMPONENTTYPEID IN (?, ?) 
GROUP BY CT.NAME, CT.COMPONENTTYPEID
ORDER BY CT.COMPONENTTYPEID
```

The filter should be on the join clause since it is used to create the resultset of the joined table.

Answer (score 2):

You either need to have a compound whereclause, otherwise you invalide your left join..

```
SELECT COUNT(CS.COMPONENTTYPEID) AS CNT
FROM COMPONENTTYPE CT 
LEFT OUTER JOIN COMPONENTSTATS CS 
  ON CS.COMPONENTTYPEID = CT.COMPONENTTYPEID
WHERE CT.COMPONENTTYPEID IN (?, ?) and (STATUS = 'Active' or Status is null)
GROUP BY CT.NAME,
         CT.COMPONENTTYPEID
ORDER BY CT.COMPONENTTYPEID
```

OR you have to put the limiting criteria on the join itself.

```
SELECT COUNT(CS.COMPONENTTYPEID) AS CNT
FROM COMPONENTTYPE CT 
LEFT OUTER JOIN COMPONENTSTATS CS 
  ON CS.COMPONENTTYPEID = CT.COMPONENTTYPEID
  AND (STATUS = 'Active')
WHERE CT.COMPONENTTYPEID IN (?, ?) 
GROUP BY CT.NAME,
         CT.COMPONENTTYPEID
ORDER BY CT.COMPONENTTYPEID
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `STATUS` Coloumn is in `COMPONENTSTATS` table, Query should be

```
SELECT COUNT(CS.COMPONENTTYPEID) AS CNT
FROM COMPONENTTYPE CT LEFT
OUTER JOIN COMPONENTSTATS CS ON CS.COMPONENTTYPEID = CT.COMPONENTTYPEID
WHERE CT.COMPONENTTYPEID IN (?, ?) AND CS.STATUS = 'Active'
GROUP BY CT.NAME,
         CT.COMPONENTTYPEID
ORDER BY CT.COMPONENTTYPEID
```